# How to click and doubleclick correctly on a QTableWidget (Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, eventfilter

I have a `QTableWidget` and I need to call some functions based on the user click on the cell.

I am currently using the following signals and slots:

```
// cellClicked(int,int)
void MyClass::on_myTableWidget_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{
    qDebug() << "Click";
}

// cellDoubleClicked(int,int)
void MyClass::on_myTableWidget_cellDoubleClicked(int row, int column)
{
    qDebug() << "Double Click";
}
```

The problem is that the `on_myTableWidget_cellClicked` is only called when I use the left mouse button. If I use the right mouse button it does not work. And the `on_myTableWidget_cellDoubleClicked` is called on both left or right mouse buttons.

What I actually want is that the `on_myTableWidget_cellClicked` be called using both the left or right mouse buttons, and that the `on_myTableWidget_cellDoubleClicked` be called only when I use the left mouse button.

How can I do that? Just using `eventFilter`? If yes how can I get the correct row from the `QTableWidget`?

I am using Qt version 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click, context menu related signal/event is being launched.

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) for more details.